# Set Maximum attempts for jquery setTimeOut

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have jQuery code that does some setTimeOut. I want to set maximum attempts that it tries to do the timeout. After "n" attempts it shouldn't time out any more. I looked up a quite a bit but couldn't figure a way. is there a way I can do it.

```
var qualv = function () {
    var isPublish = true;

    if (isPublish) {
        if ($(".qual_ol_send_box").length) {
            PopupLink.init();
        } else 
          setTimeout(qualv, 1000)
    }
  }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(qualv, 500)
    });
```

Comment: Keep a counter and then don't call setTimeout.

Comment: Everytime `isPublish` is `true` then *why setting and checking for it*?

Comment: Update:

1. I typed in the code wrong here on SO. I moved document ready out of the function now.

2. After I set isPublish and if(isPublish) there is a 3 line code that checks anotehr condition and sets it to false it it fails. I omitted here to keep the code clean

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
   var count = 0;
   var MAX_TIMEOUTS = /*yournum*/ 
   var qualv = function(count) {
      var isPublish = true;

      if(isPublish) {
        if($( ".qual_ol_send_box" ).length) { 
             PopupLink.init();
         } else 
          setTimeout(qualv,1000)
         }
         $(document).ready(function() {
             count ++;
             if(count<MAX_TIMEOUTS){
                  setTimeout(qualv(count),500)
             } else {
                  /* your best */
             }
         });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just use while

```
var qualv = function () {
    var isPublish = true;

    if (isPublish) {
        if ($(".qual_ol_send_box").length) {
            PopupLink.init();
        } else 
          setTimeout(qualv, 1000)
    }
  }
$(document).ready(function () {
    var MAX_TIMEOUTS = /*yournum*/ 
    while (i < MAX_TIMEOUTS ) {
        setTimeout(qualv, 500);
    i++;
   }
});
```